# PowerShell `Microsoft.Update.Session`; unable to download all updates

Tags: drivers, powershell, windows-update, download, updates

How can I at the very least see what `Microsoft.Update.Session` is doing behind the scene, if not identify outright why downloads are not completing?

I am using `Microsoft.Update.Session` to try and force-feed Windows 10 some updates. I have no visibility on what the COM objects are doing behind the scene, but I have seen certain items come through (audio driver, Intel storage driver...), however, the portion where I am downloading a collection of updates sits indefinitely-- last tried, it sat over the weekend.

When I force a timeout, the error returned is generic, "Operation failed for all the updates." (HResult -2145124318)

Here is the portion where the download is occurring.

```
Start-Job {
    $Downloader = $Session.CreateUpdateDownloader()
    $Downloader.Updates = $UpdateCollection
    $Downloader.Download()
} # | Wait-Job -Timeout $(1*60*60) # Seconds to wait on download
```

While here is the remainder of the script,

```
## Query-MicrosoftUpdate.ps1

$Blacklist = @(
    "*Windows 11*",
    "*BIOS*"
)

Function DisableMicrosoftUpdate {
    Param ([bool]$Status)
    $Bit = [int][bool]::Parse($Status)
    ## Temporarily enable communication with Microsoft Update
    $RegPath = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate"
    New-ItemProperty -Path $RegPath -Name "DoNotConnectToWindowsUpdateInternetLocations" -Value $Bit -PropertyType DWORD -Force
}

DisableMicrosoftUpdate $False

## Object definition
$UpdateCollection = New-Object -ComObject "Microsoft.Update.UpdateColl"
$Session = New-Object -ComObject "Microsoft.Update.Session"
$Installer = New-Object -ComObject "Microsoft.Update.Installer"

## Update check
$Criteria = "(IsInstalled=0 and DeploymentAction=*)"
$Result = $Session.CreateUpdateSearcher().Search($Criteria).Updates
$Result | Select-Object Title,Identity,IsHidden,LastDeploymentChangeTime,KBArticleIDs | `
Format-List -Property `
    Title, `
    @{l='UpdateID';e={$_.Identity.UpdateID}}, `
    @{l='PublishedDate';e={$_.LastDeploymentChangeTime.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')}}, `
    @{l='KBArticle';e={$_.KBArticleIDs}}, `
    IsHidden

$n = 0
ForEach ($Update in $Result) {
    Write-Host "Processing... $($Update.Title)"
    $Valid = $True
    ForEach ($Item in $Blacklist){If (($Update.Title -like $Item)) {$Valid = $False; $Trigger = $Item}}
    ## Add to collection if blacklisted term is not detected
    If ($Valid) {$UpdateCollection.Add($Result.Item($n))}
    Else {Write-Host "Found blacklisted item `"$Trigger`" in update title, skipping..."}
    $n++ | Out-Null
}

## Download updates in filtered collection
Start-Job {
    $Downloader = $Session.CreateUpdateDownloader()
    $Downloader.Updates = $UpdateCollection
    $Downloader.Download()
} # | Wait-Job -Timeout $(1*60*60) # Seconds to wait on download

## Install updates in filtered collection
$Installer.Updates = $UpdateCollection
$Installer.Install()

# DisableMicrosoftUpdate $True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a PowerShell script I've had to use on systems in an environment to force Windows Updates on a workstation to check in with Microsoft for its Windows Updates.

In this case the domain group policies push hard-coded WSUS registry settings to the machine to tell it where to download Windows Updates.

If the the correlated registry settings are purged, Windows Update service restarted—then before any `gpupdate` runs—it checks for Windows Updates, it'll check directly with Microsoft Internet servers for them to start downloading.

> **Essentially this:**
>
> - Removes all Windows Update domain Group Policy pushed settings
> - Stops the Windows Update service
> - Purges the local Windows Update cache and other related historical data files
> - Removes all "Computer" and "User" level ***local*** Group Policies
> - Restarts the Windows Update service
> - Forces the machine to check in, scan, and check for Windows Updates directly from Microsoft Internet servers

### PowerShell

**Warning:** *This will wipe all local group policy configurations set with `gpedit.msc`. Be sure to have backups or the configurations documented before you run this script if those are of importance.*

```
## Remove any WSUS or other hard coded WU settings and wipe old WU cache files, etc.
Remove-Item -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate" -Force -Confirm:$false;
Stop-Service -Name wuauserv -Force;
$path = "c:\windows\SoftwareDistribution";
Remove-Item -path $path -force -recurse;
 
## Wipe local GPOs
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force "C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicyUsers";
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force "C:\Windows\System32\GroupPolicy";
 
## Restart WU and force check-in
Restart-Service -Name wuauserv -Force;
1..5 | % { (New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.AutoUpdate).DetectNow(); Sleep -Seconds 3; }
c:\windows\system32\UsoClient.exe startscan;
c:\windows\system32\UsoClient.exe startinteractivescan;
```