# Windows 11 - Update stuck at "downloading 0%" but able to install using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, windows-update, windows-11-v22h2

I have a Windows 11 (Pro) - 22H2 (OS Build: 22621.1702, Windows Feature Experience Pack 1000.22641.1000.0), for some reason when I run Windows Update in the Settings screen, the updates would show up but always shows me "Downloading 0%", and this happens even if I leave my computer idle for hours (I do not have auto sleep enabled so the computer is active all the time). However at the same time I am able to using Windows Powershell Get-WindowsUpdate and Install-WindowsUpdate script to download and install updates. This happens to any type of updates regardless of whether it is security or .NET updates (or anything else). Also when running Install-WindowsUpdate the GUI Windows Update seems to all in a sudden get "woke up" and shows the downloading and installing percentages if the Install-WindowsUpdate is currently installing another update.

I have tried to disable Windows Updates (and a bunch of other services) and remove the SoftwareDistribution folder, also tried to create the Windows install USB and do a full "upgrade PC", I had MalwareBytes installed at one point but I completely removed that using their own cleanup tool.

It is not really a huge deal since I can still install updates via PowerShell, however it is just a bit weird and I would like to see if there is anything I can do to get it fixed.

Any advise for me on what else I could try? The Windows 11 was upgraded from Windows 10 Pro if that matters.

Comment: “Any advice for me on what else I could try?” - Perform a clean install of Windows to reverse the damage your actions of had on your installation

Comment: Spammy - See my answer here and give that a shot first: https://superuser.com/questions/1582778/windows-update-stuck-on-checking-for-updates/1590498#1590498. If this does not work, stop the `Windows Update` service from `services.msc` and then delete the `C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution` folder, and then start the `Windows Update` service, then run that solution at the answer I linked. Otherwise, a repair install may be warranted.

Comment: @VomitIT-ChunkyMessStyle - Thanks for your suggestion - I have already tried that a few times but no luck unfortunately. **UPDATE**: Ah my apologies, I missed the link, you've shared, there is a lot of useful info there, let me take a look, thanks again!

Comment: @Ramhound - Thanks for your suggestion, yes that would be the last resort if all others fail.

Comment: Spammy - Also see my answer here too and the **PowerShell** section in it for you to run. This answer will also purge any local group policies that affect Windows Updates on your machine: https://superuser.com/questions/1766039/powershell-microsoft-update-session-unable-to-download-all-updates/1766702#1766702. It will also purge some potential conflicting group policy set registry settings that affect allowing your machine to Windows Update right from Microsoft across the Internet. Lastly other than all those things mentioned, check any firewalls you are doing out to the Internet for blocking.

Answer (score 0):

> Any advise for me on what else I could try? The Windows 11 was
> upgraded from Windows 10 Pro

These upgrades often work but do not always work.

Patch Tuesday is monthly, so relying on Power Shell to update will get tiring soon.

**(1) Windows 11 Repair Install:**

Try this first.  Go to the Windows Media Creation Link

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows11

Windows 11 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Download.
Run the downloaded file  (double click on it).  You will need a USB key as running the download creates a USB Key.
Run Setup on the USB Key. This will launch the Repair.
Proceed normally answering the prompts.
The default Keep prompt is to Keep Everything.

**(2) Keep Everything did not work:**

The damage or corruption to the operating system and/or Windows User Profile is more serious than a standard Repair Install can fix.

Back everything up (documents, data, email), install Windows 11 fresh, let it establish its 3 partitions, and then install Apps and recover dara.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me though you must have the a internet connection. Go to windows update, advanced update ,recovery and then Advanced startup click restart now. Then go to troubleshoot, reset this Pc, then keep my files then use the cloud download to reset. Make sure to update all drivers and use all updates in settings and the play store right after download in order I gave.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).